# Having printed matter use an exclusive stylesheet

Tags: css

Currently I have my stylesheets as such:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="css/print.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
```

Is there a way to force style.css to be only on a monitor, and force print to only be on printed matter? I'm trying to make a printer-friendly page and it's taking forever to override the mass of rules in style.css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `media="screen"` on the main stylesheet so styles are only applied on a monitor screen:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" type="text/css" href="css/print.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
```

If you don't specify a `media` attribute, the stylesheet takes a default of `media="all"`, which means styles are applied everywhere.

Read more about media types [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-media-descriptors) (HTML spec) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html) (CSS spec).

Comment: I find myself placing the print stylesheet after the main stylesheet. But that shouldn't matter if you specify different media for each stylesheet.